# Updating problems in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates

Since I installed 12.04 I have problems with updating. I get lots of messages of the following kind:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.30 80]
```

Somebody has an idea of what's wrong?

Comment: It looks like that archive might not be responding, or its searching for something on that mirror that doesnt exist.  A 404 error usually means that that mirror doesnt have a package list for you...

Answer (score 1):

You can select an alternate mirror from the software center, under the "download from" menu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had already tried changing from the Main Server to the German Server, but had the same bad result. After your post I changed to the Luxembourg Server and it worked...