# problem with update

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, synaptic, aptitude

when I try to update and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this error

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `sudo apt-show-versions -i`? Are you sure you need `apt-show-versions`?

Comment: not a reference at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 218

Comment: I change my repositories, but it doewsn't help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That sounds like a bug in `apt-show-versions`. If you don't really need `apt-show-versions` you may just remove it, for example by running

```
sudo apt-get purge apt-show-versions
```

If you don't know if you need it you quite likely don't need it.

If you need the program you could at least remove the file

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-show-versions
```

and file a bug report.

Comment: works for me on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is old, but because people find it when searching for help I thought I would add another answer. Memory. If you are out of memory you will get this error. You can fix this quickly by adding swap space if you don't already have any.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same error. I am running ubuntu 14.04 server.

I determined it was because I had too many old packages hogging space.  I have been running automatic updates for over a year straight. I guess it isn't so automatic!

After running `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get clean`, I ran `apt-get purge apt-show-versions` and I am pretty sure that `apt-get autoremove` got me back in business.

It took a few attempts to finish the job -- autoremove got stuck a few times. Each time, some files would be removed and then it would crap out. It went from 4gb down to 700MB and finally 70MB.

During the process I was informed that my linux image was unstable. It was the latest version so I assume that it was related to the original problem.

After running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` everything seems to be fine

I cleared the clutter out of /boot for good measure.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I have to say I'm a beginner of Ubuntu but try to follow this guide:

[Updating problems in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150048/updating-problems-in-12-04)

Antonio says that it worked! Let's hope it will work for you too, even though the problem maybe isn't the same!