# Max. recursion depth with nested structures exceeded at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Storable.pm line 278, at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 271

Tags: apt

Excuting `apt-update & apt-upgrade -y` I'm getting this error:

```
Max. recursion depth with nested structures exceeded at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Storable.pm line 278, at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 271.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

- I reinstalled apt-show-versions
- I upgraded CPAN modules

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bug to me: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=898090

Comment: Is it on purpose you are using a local perl installation and not the system provide one?

Comment: I'm using the system's. This behaviour started after i upgraded the cpan modules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [problem with update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221038/problem-with-update)

Answer (score 1):

Install `cpanminus`:

```
apt-get install cpanminus
cpanm --uninstall Storable
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: i've tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: ! Storage is not found in the following directories and can't be uninstalled.

  /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2
  /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2

Comment: My bad, I don't know why I missed that.  Long story short if you enable it when you run a upgrade with cpan, it breaks apt functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was literally pacing up and down trying to figure out how this same problem could happen to me out of the blue.

Then I realized it was after adding a repository to my **apt package manager** via the
***/etc/apt/sources.list*** file and downloading a package that the issue occurred.

I came up with this result after running **apt-show-versions -i -v** from my terminal with the following result:

```
apt-show-versions -i -v

Parsing /var/lib/dpkg/status... completed.
Parsing /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_stretch_non-free_binary- i386_Packages... completed.
Parsing /var/lib/apt/lists/download.webmin.com_download_repository_dists_sarge_contrib_binary-i386_Packages... completed.
Parsing /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_stretch_contrib_binary-i386_Packages... completed.
Parsing /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_stretch_main_binary-i386_Packages... completed.
Max. recursion depth with nested structures exceeded at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/Storable.pm line 278, at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 271.
```

The above indicated that my issue was actually that I had too many packages downloaded from many different repositories, and together all the repositories probably had too many packages in their package data for the **Storage** module to read and handle.

My **/etc/apt/sources.list** file originally looked like:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb https://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
```

and after commenting out one of the directories, the issue resolved itself:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb https://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
```

However, this is more likely a workaround as this is probably a bug in the **perl storage** module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Debian but ran into a similar issue (the cpanminus fix didn't work for me).

The original issue has been reported as a bug [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?archive=no&bug=912695)

I've implemented their suggested workaround which solves the problem for the time being.  This involved amending the apt-show-versions script with the following lines...

```
$Storable::recursion_limit=-1;
$Storable::recursion_limit_hash=-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a solution found in the [original bug report thread](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?archive=no&bug=912695#78) to change line 271 in /usr/bin/apt-show-versions from:

```
($< == 0) and (nstore($apackages, $apackagescachefile) or
```

to

```
($< == 131072) and (nstore($apackages, $apackagescachefile) or
```

After that change, it's working perfectly for me. Not sure if that will work for everyone, but it's a lead.